# How to get distribution GUID of an media manager image using coreservice where input will be a ecl tag

Tags: core-service, media-manager, sites-9.1

In sites 9.1, there is media manager connector present.
**Task 1:** I want to read all ecl tags from tridion component and stored in a file using Core  Services which is not an issue. even i am getting tcm ids of each ecl item created under stubs folder.
**Step 2:** i want to read Distribution GUID of each ecl tags retrieved from task 1. that means for 'Task 2' i will provide input as 'ecl:0-mm-1234-dist-file' and i will get output as corresponding distribution GUID.
Please help to achieve task 2 or any suggestion will be helpful.

note: In tridion if I search directly with ecl tags then direct ecl item is opening which has external metadata and guid is part of that metadata. same information is not present as part of stubs component metadata.

Following are the screen shots:

1. direct ecl item:
   [image]
2. Stubs component:
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to [ECL API reference](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/691586/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/api-reference-documentation-downloads) for more details.Not sure if you can do this using core service.

Comment: Officially, Core Service doesn’t have knowledge about ECL URIs, so you should use the ECL Service, indeed. If you *really* want to use Core Service, you could use the implementation detail that the Title of an ECL Stub Component is an ECL URI.